# BMS adjusting charge current

Tags: charge, bms

I use this ready module for 3S battery group.

Due to high charge rate (pull about 2-3A from power supply) a high current power supply also needs.

I want to reduce charge rate up to 0.2C or 0.1C. No problem charging slowly.

Is there a way adjust this charge rate and making slowly charge on the module?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does the schematic have to do with the board? They might represent the same thing, but since the ports on the board are differently labeled, I'd at least be *careful*.

Comment: It's not the BMS' s job to set or regulate the charge current; that's the charger's job. The BMS is a security measure to make sure the cells aren't charged/discharged with out-of-spec voltages/currents; some also do cell balancing. Charging current should be set by the charger.

Comment: Thank for the answer. How battery capacity effects this charging rate? Can we say 1200mAh batteries draw less current then 2000mAh while charging? Also i use standart wall type power adapter, how can i set rate?

Comment: The charge rate is determined by what rate the charger wants to use to charge. But now you talk about standard wall type power adapter, and ask how to set the rate, so you are not using a charger, you are using a power supply? A power supply is not a charger, you need a charger.

Comment: Actually, I want to use it in a closed box with an enclosure and powered by an adapter. There's no way I can take the batteries out of the box and put them on charge. But although the circuit does not draw much current (<0.5A), it draws about 3A while the batteries are charging. Can I charge it with an adapter? instead of charger.

Comment: Battery capacity has no effect on charge current in the CC phase of charging. You are looking for a charger design that has, or lets you set, the charge current you want (and has the correct CV and cutoff settings)

Comment: @berker I already said that a power supply, or adapter as you call it, is not a proper device for charging batteries. Batteries need to be charged properly, according to their chemistry, not with a power supply. You need a charger between the power supply and battery. And before you ask, a BMS is not a charger either. Buy a charger. Please stop using the adapter as it may damage the batteries, and damaged batteries can be dangerous as they might explode or burst into fire. The batteries may already be damaged, so I recommend recycling them and buying new ones.

Comment: I'm in the exact same dilemma. I created a UPS for my router + modem. The adapter needs to charge the battery and run the routers when power is available. Using low internal-resistance good quality batteries consumes about 4 amps of power and makes the battery hot. I can bump the voltage and use a resistor to drop the voltage so it also limits the current, but I've calculated it will waste huge amount of power, like 20 watts or so. I can't use a charger because it's a UPS and I can't take out batteries to charge, and put batteries when power is out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A BMS is not the device that decides the charging current.

Neither is the power supply.

It is the lithium charger that defines the charging current. The charger is the device that takes power from power supply and safely charges the lithium batteries.

The BMS, even if it has overcurrent and overvoltage protection, is only the last line of protection if the charger has failed to prevent further damage.

Do not connect a power supply directly to the BMS or batteries. The batteries or the power supply may be damaged, and damaged batteries are dangerous.

You need a charger which can charge the batteries with the current you want.